# script "insertbefore" not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="sub-main1">Content</div>
    <div class="sub-main2">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="sub-main1">Content</div>
    <div class="sub-main2">Content</div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to move `sub-main2` above `sub-main1`. And I have used this script:

```
jQuery( ".sub-main2" ).insertBefore( jQuery( ".sub-main1" ) );
```

Now, each div with class `main` has 2 divs with class `sub-main2`.

Can someone please help me with where I am making the mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: `jQuery( ".sub-main2" )` simply selects _all_ the elements with that class, across the whole document. And then you say, "takes this set of two elements, and insert it before every `.sub-main1` element". You need to approach this by looping over the `.main` elements, and then explicitly target only the elements in the current one each time.

Comment: `$('.main .sub-main2').each(function() { $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev()); });` - https://jsfiddle.net/evoLkt36/

Answer (score 1):

You should loop in each `main` element, and then do the insert operation for sub-mains of *that* `main` element.

```js
      jQuery('.main').each(function () {
        var subMain1 = jQuery(this).find('.sub-main1');
        var subMain2 = jQuery(this).find('.sub-main2');
        subMain2.insertBefore(subMain1);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="sub-main1">main 1 Content 1</div>
    <div class="sub-main2">main 1 Content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sub-main1">main 2 Content 1</div>
    <div class="sub-main2">main 2 Content 2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Or if the .main is not always known, he could select .sub-main2 and for each of that find the parent and then .sub-main1 within that parent

Answer (score 0):

Your code is selecting all `.sub-main2` elements and places them before all of `.sub-main1` elements. That's why you get repeated once.

You need to apply a loop where you can find individual `.sub-main2` to place before the corresponding `.sub-main1` one.

Do it like this:

```
$('.sub-main2').each(function() { $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev()); });
```

Working snippet:

```js
$('.sub-main2').each(function() { $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev()); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="sub-main1">Content1-1</div>
    <div class="sub-main2">Content1-2</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="sub-main1">Content2-1</div>
    <div class="sub-main2">Content2-2</div>
</div>
```